# iPhone simulator location is wrong

Tags: javascript, location, ios-simulator

I'm exploring location services, and my iOS Simulator on Xcode 4.6 is showing the wrong latitude and longitude. I've done this in two ways, with CLLocation manager instance, and with using HTML5 Geolocation and Cordova. The same javascript works perfectly on a web browser, but not from the simulator. I get the same wrong coordinates using the CLLocation manager as well. Is this a problem with the simulator, and how can I fix it?

Comment: In the iOS Simulator, in the Debug menu you should see a Location option ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a feature; the simulator is not supposed to be real, it's supposed to **simulate**, to let you customize the environment in order to test your program. It gives you the option in the debug menu to set the location for it to use, as Nirk said. This way you can make sure it functions correctly with some arbitrary locations.

Comment: Thank you! I do have a provisional license, so I will probably run it on my actual iDevice to check if there's actually something wrong with my code.

Comment: This is a horrible bug, not a feature.   My Apple AirBook knows its current location perfectly.

So why can't the iOS simulator ask MacOS for its current location, and use that?   If I need to simulate other locations, I can do that, but the default should be to give the current location when it is known.

Comment: What is insanely dumb is that it doesn't by default find your computer's location. Sure, let it be configurable, but have smart defaults.

Comment: It might not be a bug, but please don't call it a feature. A feature would have been the possibility to fake a location during development. If anything, this is a lack of a feature.